# Why is red wine often paired with red meat?

Tags: pairing, red-wine

When we think of red meat we usually think of a heavy meal, right? Well that's kinda what red wine represents in the wine world...

Once again I ask: Why is red wine often paired with red meat?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to know which wine goes with which type of food](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/4979/how-to-know-which-wine-goes-with-which-type-of-food)

Answer (score 2):

**Why is red wine often paired with red meat?**

The old wine pairing phrase goes as thus: “red with red meat and white with fish”. But wine pairing is generally a little more complicated than that.

Here is how Dr. Vinifera puts it:

> **The reason red wine typically pairs well with red meat is that red wine tends to be higher in tannins.** While on their own, tannins can feel drying, they’re a good complement to the rich fattiness that can be found in red meat. White wine can be better with fish or chicken because it tends to have higher acidity, and it complements food similarly to how a squirt of lemon juice can brighten a seafood dish.
>
> But those are just general rules. If you look at how a dish is prepared—say, grilled vs. poached, or sautéed in a bunch of butter, or take into account the side dishes or the setting, you might come up with different pairings based on the situation. So while a chewy grilled steak might call for a robust red, a sautéed filet mignon served with béchamel sauce and rosemary potatoes might work better with a rich, full-bodied white. - [Why is white meat served with white wine and red meat with red?](https://www.winespectator.com/drvinny/show/id/50063)